# Having issue with JavaScript calling convention

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the snapshot of the code:

[image]

If the function **testFields** at `Line:3` returns false, the control rightly goes to `Line:21` and returns *false*. If **testFields** returns *true*, the control goes to `Line:4` and then instead of going on to handle the response returned in function at `Line:5`, the control goes on to `Line:21`, where the **retVal** is still *false*. That is, condition to `Line:6` is checked after the function has returned a value to the function:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return validateInput()" />
```

Where as, logically, it should first test the condition at `Line:7` then decide whether `retVal` should be *true* or let it be default *false* and then value should be returned via `Line:21`.

What is logically wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are two ways.**

1. You can make synchronous ajax request.

   ```
   var retVal ;
   $.ajax({ 
       url: youUrl,
       async: false, // required to pause script until request is done
       success: function( ret ) { 
          retVal = ret; // ret is invisible outside this callback

       },
       error : function( err ) {
         // your error logic
       }

   });
   //We'll in this line if request is completed and either success or error callback  was called.  
   return retVal;
   ```
2. But if you don't want the script been stopped. You can prevent a default action in form, and send the form from callback  such as:

   ```
   $( "form" ).submit( function( e, extra ) { 

     if( !extra )
       $.post( 
         url: "script.php",
         data: "yourdata",
         success: function( ) {  
           $( "form" ).trigger( "submit", [true] );         
         },
        error: function(){}
    );

      // extra parameter will be always undefined until we'll not pass it in an array which will be aplied to listener as  next ones arguments - take a look at success callback
     return !!extra  // doubled negate operator ensures that extra will be returned as boolean because if you return undefined  that means you didn't return anything 
   });
   ```

and in html form tag without onsubmit declaration :

```
<form method="POST" />
```

Comment: Changed to +1 with the addition of an asynchronous solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your code: this is the way asynchronous functions work. Ajax is intended to by asynchronous, which means the line of code after the `$.post()` function call -  in your case the end of the `if` and the `return` on line 21 - will be executed immediately. Meanwhile, the browser sends off the ajax request and when a response comes in it *then* calls your success (or error) callback function at line 5.

Although you can set a flag to make the call *synchronous*, that is, to make code execution stop at that point until a response comes back, this is almost never a good idea because it also stops the browser from repainting or otherwise responding to the user. Better to get used to structuring your code in such a way that you continue processing from within the callback function - that's pretty much the standard way of the web these days.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I forgot the role of first **A** in AJAX. I need to restructure the code as **abuduba** quoted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solution by @abuduba, the following code will also work.

[image]

Here **btnSubmit** is not a button of type 'submit' but a simple button.

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```